# Traveling to Italy, then France, then Spain. In what country should I apply for my Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, italy, spain

I'm planning a trip to Italy, France, and Spain next year.  I will be flying into Rome, Italy, and will be spending 2 nights there and 2 nights in Florence.  Then I will travel to Côte d'Azur, France, and will spend 1 night there and 1 night in Provence.  After that, I will travel to Barcelona, Spain, and spend 2 nights there before flying home to America.

I was curious as to what country I should apply for my visa in.  All 3 of the countries I will be visiting are Schengen states.  However, I have heard that Spain does not accept visas issued from other Schengen countries.  Where should I apply for my visa?  Do I need just 1, or do I need 2 or even 3?

I've never traveled outside of the United States before, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: The need for visas is predicated upon the type of passport you have. We have lots of people from everywhere, some need visas some don't.  What sort of passport will you use? Presumably American, but you will need to clarify.  Close voting as unclear.

Comment: _Do I need just 1, or do I need 2 or even 3?_ the Schengen scheme makes it so that you only need one visa to travel between member states, so **if you were to need a visa** you would only need one.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be a US citizen, as you have never been outside the US.

US citizens do not need visas for visits to the Schengen area, as long as they are not present in the Schengen area for no more than 90 days in any 180-day period.

If you are not a US citizen, please update your question.

The claim that Spain does not accept Schengen visas issued by other countries is ludicrous, though it's possible that someone arrived at that conclusion by misinterpreting some other situation.  I won't speculate further on that.

If you were of a nationality that required a Schengen visa, for the itinerary you described, you would normally apply to Italy because, based on the duration of stay, that is your main destination.  As you are (apparently) a US citizen, however, you need not worry about that whatsoever.