# To which Schengen country should I apply for multiple city travels?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am traveling to Amsterdam (2 nights), Paris (2 Nights), Rome (3 nights) and Zurich (3 nights). However, I am landing in Brussels and then taking a train on the same day to Amsterdam. To which country should I apply for the visa?

Comment: Please check the [link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51459/traveling-to-italy-then-france-then-spain-in-what-country-should-i-apply-for?rq=1) for your question..